# AWS mTLS access to load balanced EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a cluster of private EC2 instances serving http requests behind a public ALB. https termination happens on the ALB, with authentication on the EC2 instances.  I want to move authentication to the ALB, ideally via mTLS. But ALB does not support mTLS. From some initial reading, it sounds like API Gateway can replace load balancing/firewall functions of the ALB in this design, while also supporting mTLS?  Is that correct?

If so, I wonder what would be the best way to implement sticky sessions, which seem not supported by API Gateway, but needed by my app.  I guess client request could initially target an API served by any instance, but then subsequent requests would target API unique to the instance that replied?

Are there other drawbacks to API Gateway, other than higher cost at high volume?  Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: "From some initial reading, it sounds like API Gateway can replace load balancing/firewall functions of the ALB in this design, while also supporting mTLS? Is that correct?" That doesn't sound correct to me. API Gateway won't do load balancing for you. You would still need to have a load balancer behind the API Gateway.

Comment: You can switch to a Network Load Balancer, configured with TCP passthrough, and IP based stickiness. Then you could serve an SSL certificate from your backend server(s) instead of the load balancer, and perform mTLS authentication on the servers.

Comment: @MarkB, you are right, I guess interchangeable only if backend service is already scaleable, and just need public facing frontend.  In my case, I really don't need load balancing, only fail-over and firewall function, so maybe it will work with LB. I will look into how it handles unreachable route.

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumptions were incorrect.  API Gateway is not an alternative to ALB except in some specialized circumstances.  So, the solution for me is to put an API Gateway in front of a private ALB, e.g., as described in AWS example
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-alb-integration/